# teleop_twist_joy with Logitech F710 Joystick force feedback error

Tags: mobile-robot, control, ros

I am using a Logitech F710 joystick game controller in ROS Kinetic Kame. I was able to perform `jstest` testing, and can see my joystick works well.

But when I try to use joystick with Turtlesim or with simple teleop_twist_joy, I see this error :`[ERROR] [1567106281.990244467]: Couldn't open joystick force feedback!` and there is no response on the screen in turtlesim or in the terminal itself.

Here's entire terminal log:

```
$user@user: roslaunch teleop_twist_joy teleop.launch ... logging to /home/sma1/.ros/log/2bdd147a-ca8f-11e9-80dc-5891cf766ee3/roslaunch-user-14722.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://user:44089/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /joy_node/autorepeat_rate: 20
 * /joy_node/deadzone: 0.3
 * /joy_node/dev: /dev/input/js0
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /teleop_twist_joy/axis_angular: 0
 * /teleop_twist_joy/axis_linear: 1
 * /teleop_twist_joy/enable_button: 8
 * /teleop_twist_joy/enable_turbo_button: 10
 * /teleop_twist_joy/scale_angular: 0.4
 * /teleop_twist_joy/scale_linear: 0.7
 * /teleop_twist_joy/scale_linear_turbo: 1.5

NODES
  /
    joy_node (joy/joy_node)
    teleop_twist_joy (teleop_twist_joy/teleop_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[joy_node-1]: started with pid [14739]
process[teleop_twist_joy-2]: started with pid [14740]
[ERROR] [1567106281.990244467]: Couldn't open joystick force feedback!
```

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Deep. What troubleshooting have you done? I googled your error and found [this page](https://answers.ros.org/question/218450/solved-couldnt-open-joystick-devinputjs0/) towards the top of the results, with the following comment on the accepted answer: `The problem was that I had not set ROS_IP on my remote machine.` Have you tried checking these or other settings mentioned in that post?

Comment: Thank you @Chuck for welcoming me. Before posting it here, I did following troubleshooting: 

- checked if the controller is actually working with the ROS by following this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/ConfiguringALinuxJoystick
- did a quick google search, and found that and many other post, and most of them said to ignore this error, but in my case it doesn't help.
- The one you posted is for actual turtlebot, and in my case I am using simulation, looks like ROS is unable to open the controller.

Comment: I am trying to use a Logitech F710 controller to a single machine, which runs ROS Kinetic Kame and turtlesim or teleop_twist_joy node in the same environment.

Comment: I checked issues list on ros-drivers github page, and everyone says to ignore, but then why I am unable to see any response with teleop node? It only works with `jstest`

Answer (score 0):

I think your ROS joy node isn't configured correctly, which would explain the failure with `teleop_twist_joy`, because that package subscribes to `sensor_msgs/Joy`. You said that the joystick is working with `jstest`, but that's a test to see if your machine can use the joystick. It's not a ROS test.

You said you [followed the Configure a Joystick tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/ConfiguringALinuxJoystick); what do you get when you do the following (from the tutorial):

> Now let's make the joystick accessible for the ROS joy node. Start by listing the permissions of the joystick:
>
> `$ ls -l /dev/input/jsX`
>
> You will see something similar to:
>
> `crw-rw-XX- 1 root dialout 188, 0 2009-08-14 12:04 /dev/input/jsX`
>
> If XX is rw: the js device is configured properly.
>
> If XX is --: the js device is not configured properly and you need to:
>
> `$ sudo chmod a+rw /dev/input/jsX`

What do you get when you try to listen to the `sensor_msgs/Joy` output?

> `$ rostopic echo joy`

Comment: I followed that tutorial, and was able to see the keystroke values on the console with `rostopic echo joy`. That made me say that it works with the ROS.

Comment: @Deep - you haven't addressed the points I made. What do you get when you check permissions? What do you get when you echo the joy topic?